# Access-Control-Allow-Origin for any domain

Tags: php, web-services

I use remot3.it to access some web servers hosted on devices over the internet. Remot3 assigns random URLs for accessing these devices. Some webpages hosted on these devices need to call a webservice I have hosted on a cloud server. But, when I try to call these services, I get the following error:

```
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://hasconpanel.ckoysolutions.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'https://aatqtezo.p72.rt3.io' is therefore not allowed access.
```

"aatqtezo.p72.rt3.io" is only a random URL, this URL changes every time I access the device using remot3. I think I have to allow origins from any domain/URL for calling the webservice.

How do I set `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ');` to allow calls from any site?

Answer (score 0):

you must set is in web servers

in appache server put in to **.htaccess** file and enable **mod headers** :

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
</ifModule>
```

Comment: I need to add this to the server being called right? That means the server that is hosted on cloud?

Comment: It is usable in the host